# Setting an image button in CSS - image:active

Tags: css

I'm trying to replace the submit button with an image by defining it in a `class="myButton"` and change the styles in CSS. the `myButton:active` doesn't seem to work when being clicked.

Here is my CSS:

```css
.myButton{
    background:url(./images/but.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:none;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

myButton:active {
     background:url(./images/but2.png) no-repeat;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<input class="myButton" type="submit" value="">
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/kDnsn/2/) . You were missing `.` before `myButton`. It was a small error. :)

```css
.myButton{
    background:url(./images/but.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:none;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

.myButton:active  /* use Dot here */
{   
    background:url(./images/but2.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<form action="desired Link">
  <button>  <img src="desired image URL"/>
  </button>
</form>
<style> 

</style>
```