# Add image to button Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Hi my submit button is like this:

```
 {!! Form::open([
                        'id' => 'form-id',
                        'method' => 'delete',
                        'action' => ['ToDoListController@delete', $task->id],
                    ]) !!}

                        {!! Form::submit('Delete', [
                            'id' => 'my-id',
                            'name' => 'bt_add',
                            'image' => '../../images/delete.jpg',

                    ]) !!}

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I want to add image to my button but don't know how. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a button?

`<button type="submit" id="my-id" name="btn_add"><img src=""></button>`

Comment: There no such thing as form button image in laravel. your third parameter will be set as data-attribute in your html. If you want you can create a macro that wrap your logic. Anyway laravel form is still html in the end

Answer (score 0):

You can add a css class to your button and then define the image to be used in that class e.g.

```
{!! Form::submit('Delete', [
    'id' => 'my-id',
    'name' => 'bt_add',
    'class' => 'bt_add',
]) !!}
```

In the css...

```
.bt_add {
    background:url(/images/Btn.PNG) no-repeat;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: none;
}
```

Sorry I haven't tested this (bit of a hurry) but this should give you the effect you want. See other posts on button images e.g. [Setting an image button in CSS - image:active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543697/setting-an-image-button-in-css-imageactive)